# bringing back in garbage pails on Yom Tov

Tags: yom-tov, muktzeh, disposal

If your garbage gets picked up on Yom Tov are you allowed to bring back into your property your garbage pails on Yom Tov?

Comment: Maybe you could also ask: if not, are there any contrivances which would allow you to do so?

Comment: http://dinonline.org/2015/01/05/bringing-in-garbage-bin-on-shabbos/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are allowed to bring them back in.
See [Rivevos Ephraim 1:222:19](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1081&st=&pgnum=176) who writes that you can do so as you'll need to use it for more trash, and you may be worried that someone will take your trash can. It would be ideal to wait until after Yom Tov, though.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, at least in general, something considered *muktze* at the start of *yom tov* is *muktze* for the entirety of *yom tov* [1]; something like garbage for which there is no use (or which is *maus* or which is specifically set aside for non-use) is AFAIK generally *muktze* [2]; and a *basis* (base, or container, or support) for only *muktze* things is generally AFAIK *muktze* [3]. Putting those three things together would seem to imply that a garbage can cannot be brought back in on *yom tov*. But, as always, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR)!

Sources:
[1] E.g., *Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah* (Hebrew edition) 21:1, 20:3, 20:46, 22:1, 22:8.
[2] E.g., *SSK* 20:25-27, q.v. and cf. 20:41 paragraph 3.
[3] E.g., *SSK* 20:46.

Answer (score 2):

A garbage pail that contained garbage at the onset of Y"T is muktza because it is "basis" to a muktze.

If emptied on Y"T by city sanitation, you are not permitted to return it to its place. This is because it was muktza at nightfall (bein hashmoshos), and that renders it muktza for the remainder of the day (known as "migu dIskatzoi").

However, on the second day of Y"T, it is permitted. The rule is that which is muktza due to its state during the previous nightfall does not renew during a subsequent nightfall.

As always, consult your rabbi. It is possible that your rabbi would consider a (dirty) garbage pail intrinsically muktza.

Answer (score 1):

in the kitzur it says that on yom tov because cooking is permissible, people will tend to be lenient in other things as well. so to counteract this tendency we are more stringent about muktzeh

Comment: I also do not see why not. However many people do not, and yet no one has been able to give me a good reason why not.

Comment: it's probably mutzeh because it is not needed for yom tov? unless u truely need it (and kept this in mind before yom tov), wouldnt u agree?