# Can one take out trash cans to the street on Yom Tov?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, yom-tov, muktzeh, disposal

I know that trash is generally accepted as muktze, though can be moved due to 'graf shel rei'.
Is one allowed to take the trash cans out to the street on Shabbos and Yom Tov to the street for pickup?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3116

Comment: Our rav has said that one should put the can onto the curb *before Yom Tov*. one is then allowed to put the garbage bas from the house into the can on Yom Tov. Once the garbage has been picked up, wait until after Yom Tov to put the empty can back on the side of the house. This is from memory so I am leaving it a comment.

Comment: there are severalctypes of muktse, some of them can be moved in special conditions

Comment: Please translate 'graf shel rei'.'. I assume it has something to do with stink.

Comment: @sabbahillel Perhaps, a piece of answering this question is an aspect of how the trash is picked up. Chances are, the town sanitation department will not stop at your home if they do not see a trash can, there. So, by placing one there, aren't they specifically doing *melacha* for your benefit and you are casuing them to do this? If so, how would placing the trash before Shabbat or Yom Tov resolve this problem?

Comment: @DanF there is a svara that Reb Yaakov said in the Emes Liyaakov on Shulchan aruch that utility companies are always doing al daatei diatzmam (for their own benefit) since they are legally obligated to perform their job.

Comment: @sabba that is definitely a popular psak. I haven't looked into it in a while but there is a big question on that. The fact that garbage cans are made to be moved around means that they are not huktza bimkomam. Same as the pull out garbage cans people have built into their kitchen cabinets.

Comment: @user6591 That refers to the general job description and job function. They are required to collect trash when they see it. If they don't see a trash can on your lawn or in the area where they expect to collect it, they are not required to stop at your home at all. Thus, it could be that putting out trash causes them to stop at your home. This is similar to taking a city bus on Shabbat. Your waiting at the stop causes the driver to stop specifically for you.

Comment: @DanF According to my rav when something is *disgusting*, it can be removed from the house and placed somewhere outside. Once it has been placed outside, it cannot be moved again. If the empty cans are in the front (where the garbagemen would pick them up), then one can place the garbage in the cans. If the cans are at the side of the house, and the garbage put into them, then the cans cannot be moved to the curb.

Comment: @sabbahillel Is there a halachic definition / parameter of "disgusting", or  is that decision left to the individual? This sounds like a broad , imprecise definition.

Comment: @DanF If there is a power outage in a Jewish bungalow colony and the electric company comes to fix it on shabbot, you may not benefit from the lights that now work if not for this svara. I've never heard of a gramma like this. It is not assur to cross the street causing a car to slow down in the process.  (Foolish maybe.)

Comment: @user6591 Re last sentence - actually, according to a number of opinions I have heard from, it IS prohibited. Re electric company, you didn't cause the outage, and I assume no one from the colony called the electric company. I don't see the analogy.

Comment: @DanF If you can link a source I'd be interested to see that. There is no gramma for non jews even when doing an act expressly for a jew. That's why they can open a fridge even if the light will go on. In any case I've really never heard of any objection to taking out the paper and the trash except for muktza issues.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Rabbi Ephraim Greenblatt ([Rivevos Ephraim 7:303:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1083&pgnum=265)) writes that it is best to take them out before Yom Tov, but you can take them out on Yom Tov.

> פה המנהג שמוציאים את פח הזבל לרחוק ביום ג׳ ויום ו׳ ומשם באים הגוים שעובדים עבור העריה ומריקים, ומותר להוציא בחוץ כגרף של רעי או שאינו מוקצה, (או אולי יותר טוב להוציא לפני יום טוב),